# How to persist Angular mat-paginator data?

Tags: angular, angular-material, pagination, paginator

Our project have over ten tables with different types of data. For each table we already use `mat-paginator` to pagination goals. Now I want to add persistence so next time user open one of tables he/she could view data sorted in the same way as he/she has sorted it the previous time.

I could not find any information about persistence feature for `mat-paginator` on official [Angular Material site](https://material.angular.io/components/paginator/overview).

Could someone point me out how is it better to implement such functionality in Angular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at the API tab of [the mat paginator documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/paginator/api#MatPaginator) you can see it accepts `pageIndex` and `pageSize` as inputs.

I would go ahead and use this part of the mat-paginator API to set the page size and page index to my liking. I would then go ahead and save the state of my paginators in [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) or [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) (depending on the persistence needs), then read the values I need on page load and set up the paginators.

Comment: Thanks @Octavian Mărculescu I used the same approach but decided to ask community about some magic predefined method in Angular